# SQL to retrieve the latest records, grouping by unique foreign keys

Tags: sql, mysql, database, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I'm creating query to retrieve the latest posts in a forum using a SQL DB.

I've got a table called "Post". Each post has a foreign key relation to a "Thread" and a "User" as well as a creation date.

The trick is I don't want to show two posts by the same user or two posts in the same thread. Is it possible to create a query that contains all this logic?

```
# Grab the last 10 posts.
SELECT id, user_id, thread_id
FROM posts
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10;

# Grab the last 10 posts, max one post per user
SELECT id, user_id, thread_id
FROM post
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10;

# Grab the last 10 posts, max one post per user, max one post per thread???
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see if it helps :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
id, user_id, thread_id 
FROM posts 
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10;

SELECT DISTINCT
id, user_id, thread_id
FROM post
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

You can also see a [tutorial](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx)  about this and a [discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/712563-using-distinct-get-unique-results) about this.

cheers! :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would DISTINCT help? Isn't the id column pk?

Comment: DISTINCT won't help - because ID will always be distinct!

Comment: I knew DISTINCT was part of the solution but wasn't sure of the exact use of it so included a tutorial link to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but give this a try:

```
(
  SELECT p1.id, p1.user_id, p1.thread_id
  FROM post AS p1 LEFT OUTER JOIN post AS p2
    ON (p1.user_id = p2.user_id AND p1.date < p2.date)
  WHERE p2.id IS NULL
  ORDER BY p1.date DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
UNION DISTINCT
(
  SELECT p3.id, p3.user_id, p3.thread_id
  FROM post AS p3 LEFT OUTER JOIN post AS p4
    ON (p3.thread_id = p4.thread_id AND p3.date < p4.date)
  WHERE p4.id IS NULL
  ORDER BY p3.date DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? The first query for per user, the second for per user and per thread.

```
SELECT id, user_id, thread_id
FROM post p1
WHERE id = (SELECT id 
            FROM post 
            WHERE user_id = p1.user_id 
            ORDER BY date DESC 
            LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 10;

SELECT id, user_id, thread_id
FROM post p1
WHERE id = (SELECT id 
            FROM post 
            WHERE user_id = p1.user_id 
            ORDER BY date DESC 
            LIMIT 1) 
AND id = (SELECT id 
          FROM post 
          WHERE thread_id = p1.thread_id 
          ORDER BY date DESC 
          LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: If you only get 10 records on the first query, you could end up with less than 10 on the second right?

Comment: @jbox, Yes, of course, there're cases when both queries can end up with less then 10 rows.
In first query, it could be possible, if there aren't 10 users, that have posted smth. In the second one it would be, when there aren't 10 threads by 10 different users.

Comment: @jbox, Query just finds the last post for current user and current thread. Did you try it?